# Is there an easy way to bind Java immutable objects with optional fields in a query?

Tags: java, binding, option-type, dao

I am inserting an immutable object with `Optional` fields using a DAO and want to use the `@BindBean` annotation to bind the object to query parameters. This is not working because of the `Optional` fields.

My attempt to solve this problem was to make a custom Binder, but I feel there must be a more maintainable way.

This is how I'm creating my DAO statement:

```
@GetGeneratedKeys
@SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO TASKS (project_id, creator_id, stage, title, description, created_at, priority, est_work)" +
           "VALUES (:projectId, :creatorId, :stage, :title, :description, :createdAt, :priority, :estimatedWork)")
int insertTask(@NewTaskBinder ImmutableNewTask newTask);
```

This is my current solution:

```
@BindingAnnotation(NewTaskBinder.NewTaskBinderFactory.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface NewTaskBinder {
    class NewTaskBinderFactory implements BinderFactory {

        @Override
        public Binder build(Annotation t) {
            return (Binder<NewTaskBinder, ImmutableNewTask>) (query, bind, newTask) -> {
                query.bind("title", newTask.getTitle());
                query.bind("stage", newTask.getStage());
                query.bind("creatorId", newTask.getCreatorId());
                query.bind("projectId", newTask.getProjectId());
                query.bind("createdAt", new Date());
                query.bind("dueDate", newTask.getDueDate().orElse(null));
                query.bind("priority", newTask.getPriority().orElse(null));
                query.bind("description", newTask.getDescription().orElse(null));
                query.bind("estimatedWork", newTask.getEstimatedWork().orElse(null));
            };
        }
    }
}
```

`@BindBean` works great without `Optional` fields present. It would be great if there's a way to adjust this to work with Optionals.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. `Optional` in Java is (primarily) for return values from methods. For fields just use plain old nullable references.

Comment: I'm using the Immutable library for my objects. According to my understanding, using `Optional` is how to set optional fields. https://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#optional-attributes